# moment.js how to print this week in a specific format

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to print the current week from Mon to Sun using moment.js as

- Mon, 4th Jun
- Tue, 5th Jun
- and so on

I saw `moment().format('ddd, MMM Do')` can print the desired format. And `moment().startOf('week').toString()` gives the correct first day of week but in different format.

`moment.adḍ̣(1, 'day')` can give next day and so on.

My trouble is how to combine this to print all days of the week starting from first day.

Comment: Can you please post the code which you have tried?

Answer (score 3):

Here `weekDateStr` will contain formatted string for current week

```
var weekDateStr = [];
var date = moment().startOf('week');
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    console.log(date.format('ddd, MMM Do'));
    weekDateStr.push(date.format('ddd, MMM Do'));
    date = date.adḍ̣(1, 'day')
}
console.log(weekDateStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `moment().startOf('week').toString()` like that. `toString()` just converts object to its string representation, but the information that you need is contained within the object obtained by calling `moment().startOf('week')`.

If you want the mentioned format then you can easily change it to `moment().startOf('week').format('ddd, MMM Do')`. And then just keep adding days (using `add(i, 'days')`) to that start of the week in a loop until you have obtained 7 days, each time calling `.format('ddd, MMM Do')` on a given date.

```js
const dateStr = '';

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  console.log(moment().startOf('week').add(i, 'days').format('ddd, MMM Do'));
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

And if you need it as a string.

```js
const date = Array.from({length: 7}, () => 0)
  .map((v, i) => moment().startOf('week').add(i, 'day').format('ddd, MMM Do'))
  .join('; ');

console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```